# How to give a python script limited access to azure blob container

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want my python script to be able to append new blobs to my container in azure. Using Shared Access Signatures (SAS) seems to be the way to go.

But I can't figure out how to use them. I don't want to give the script full access to the azure account by giving it the storage account key so using a SAS and limiting the abilities of the script to create and removing delete, get and list seems to be ok.
But how to I use the token in the script?

Here is my test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, ContainerPermissions, ContentSettings

# this is only for testing, account key will be removed later

account_name = 'myaccountname'
account_key = 'myaccountkey'
container_name = 'mycontainer'
existing_file = 'existing_file.jpg'
new_file = 'test.jpg'

service = BlockBlobService(
    account_name=account_name,
    account_key=account_key
)
# There are two ways to create a permission
# 1. Assign boolean values to `read`/`add`/`create`/`write`/`delete` operation
# permission = BlobPermissions(read=True, add=True, create=True, write=True, delete=True)
# 2. Just simply assign a string to `_str`(A string representing the permissions) like `racwd` which means assign True to all operation
permission = ContainerPermissions(write=True)
sas = service.generate_container_shared_access_signature(
    container_name=container_name,
    permission=permission,
    protocol='https'
)
print(sas)

# Here begins the real script

service = BlockBlobService(
    account_name=account_name,
    sas_token=sas
)

assert service.exists(container_name=container_name, blob_name=existing_file)

service.create_blob_from_path(
        container_name=container_name,
        blob_name=new_file,
        file_path='./%s' % new_file,
        content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type=mimetypes.guess_type('./%s' % new_file)[0]),
        validate_content=True
)

r = requests.head('https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s/%s' % (account_name, container_name, new_file), timeout=2)
assert r.status_code == 200
```

This fails service.exists() call with: `azure.common.AzureHttpError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.`

Comment: Um... I just googled "azure sas python". First hit seems to answer your question.

Comment: Just did the same could only find outdated docs or links where people do slightly different things then I want to do. I want to get rid of the account key in my code. My script should only be allowed to upload new blobs and update existing ones. No read, no listing, no deletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it. For anyone who is interested, here is the working script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import mimetypes
mimetypes.init()
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import requests
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, ContainerPermissions, ContentSettings

account_name = 'myaccount'
account_key = 'mykey'
container_name = 'mycontainer'
new_file = 'new_pic.jpg'
existing_file = 'old_pic.jpg'

service = BlockBlobService(account_name=account_name, account_key=account_key)
permission = ContainerPermissions(read=True, write=True)
sas = service.generate_container_shared_access_signature(container_name=container_name, permission=permission,
        protocol='https', start=datetime.now(), expiry=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1))
print(sas)

service = BlockBlobService(account_name=account_name, sas_token=sas)

assert service.exists(container_name=container_name, blob_name=existing_file)

service.create_blob_from_path(
        container_name=container_name,
        blob_name=new_file,
        file_path=new_file,
        content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(new_file)[0]),
        validate_content=True
)

r = requests.head('https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s/%s' % (account_name, container_name, new_file), timeout=2)
assert r.status_code == 200
```

The important stuff is using `ContainerPermissions` and getting the datetimes right. Timezones are your worst nightmare!

Answer (score 4):

As @DavidMakogon said, it sounds like referring to the [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/03/30/uploading-files-to-azure-storage-using-sasshared-access-signature/). Indeed, that helps for your question.

According to your description, it seems that you had known how to use these methods [`generate_account_shared_access_signature`](http://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.html#azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.BaseBlobService.generate_account_shared_access_signature) with [`AccountPermission`](http://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.storage.models.html#azure.storage.models.AccountPermissions), [`generate_container_shared_access_signature`](http://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.html#azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.BaseBlobService.generate_container_shared_access_signature) with [`ContainerPermission`](http://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.storage.blob.models.html#azure.storage.blob.models.ContainerPermissions), [`generate_blob_shared_access_signature`](http://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.html#azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.BaseBlobService.generate_blob_shared_access_signature) with [`BlobPermission`](http://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.storage.blob.models.html#azure.storage.blob.models.BlobPermissions) to generate the SAS for different levels (account, container, blob), like the code below for blob level.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, BlobPermissions

account_name = '<your storage account name>'
account_key = '<your storage account key>'
container_name = 'mycontainer'

service = BlockBlobService(account_name=account_name, account_key=account_key)
# There are two ways to create a permission
# 1. Assign boolean values to `read`/`add`/`create`/`write`/`delete` operation
# permission = BlobPermissions(read=True, add=True, create=True, write=True, delete=True)
# 2. Just simply assign a string to `_str`(A string representing the permissions) like `racwd` which means assign True to all operation
permission = BlobPermissions(_str="racwd")
sas = service.generate_blob_shared_access_signature(container_name, 'test.jpg', permission)
print sas
```

For using SAS to access Azure Blob Storage in Python script, as below.

1. Using SAS for calling Blob Storgae REST API, you can refer to the document [`Service SAS Examples`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/service-sas-examples#blob-examples) to append SAS to the blob url as query parameters to do the related operation, like as below.

> ```
> GET https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/pictures/profile.jpg?sv=2012-02-12&st=2009-02-09&se=2009-02-10&sr=c&sp=r&si=YWJjZGVmZw%3d%3d&sig=dD80ihBh5jfNpymO5Hg1IdiJIEvHcJpCMiCMnN%2fRnbI%3d   
> HTTP/1.1  
> Host: myaccount.blob.core.windows.net  
> x-ms-date: <date>
> ```

2. Using SAS in Python script with Azure Storage SDK,  the construct method of classes [`BlockBlobService`](http://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice.html#azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice.BlockBlobService) & [`BaseBlobService`](http://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.html#azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.BaseBlobService) have a parameter `sas_token` which be explained as below that you can pass `sas` value.

> **sas_token** (str) – A shared access signature token to use to authenticate requests instead of the account key. If account key and sas token are both specified, account key will be used to sign. If neither are specified, anonymous access will be used.

So for example, the code for `BlockBlobService` using SAS as below.

```
service = BlockBlobService(sas_token=sas)
```

Comment: Thx, this helped alot. But still I can't figure out how this works. I added my sample code to the question. Is the SAS token only valid for 1 blob or can I use it for the whole container? Because I need to provide a blob to generate it. This seems strange to me.